# dune utop some executable

Tags: ocaml, utop, ocaml-dune

For an single file executable, how can I load it in `dune utop` ?

Precisely, on a project with a library in a directory `lib` and a corresponding `dune` file, I can launch `dune utop lib` then `open Lib.MyModule` and this will load the file `MyModule.ml`.

What would be the equivalent for a project with no subdirectory, and the following files at its root, a `dune` file

```
(executable
  (name auth)
  (libraries ezjsonm cryptokit))
```

and a file `auth.ml`

```
let hi = "value"
```

where I would like to load the values from that file in `dune utop`

Comment: nb : one can always invoke   `#use "somefile.ml";;`  if that's not dependant on other libs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not supported by dune currently. You need to have a lib to use `dune utop`. It is a bit unfortunate.